# How to create a bib list?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I have a `.bib` file, and I would like to create a single PDF file with "References" in the title and then the list of all papers in the `.bib` file ordered alphabetically. The style of the bibliography list is not that important.

I could do that easily by creating a `.tex` file that uses the cite command for all the `.bib` entries. That could be tedious to update and maintain.

Is there a way to do that without using the `\nocite` command explicitly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `\nocite` command with the wildcard character: `\nocite{*}` which does the same as if you were using `\nocite` for every entry in your `.bib` file. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A2013,
author = {Author, A},
title = {A nice paper},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2013},
volume = {1},
pages = {1--2},
}
@article{B2013,
author = {Buthor, B},
title = {A wonderful paper},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2013},
volume = {1},
pages = {3--4},
}
@article{C2013,
author = {Cuthor, C},
title = {An amazing paper},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2013},
volume = {1},
pages = {5--6},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]

If your `.bib` is too large, there are some packages designed just for this, like the [`biblist`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex209/contrib/biblist) or [`listbib`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listbib) packages.
For instance, deleting the `\nocite{*}` line and adding a `\usepackage{biblist}` in your preamble, you get:
[image]